# Content in the middle

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make it title left in the middle between right and left
When you try it on your phone with a large screen the title stays in the middle
But in the small screen phone the title moves to the right

```css
.tags {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.tags:hover:after {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin: 10px 5px 15px 90px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(glose);
  left: -160%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 140px;
}

.tags:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
  bottom: 29px;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="tags" glose="Move down">Move down</a>
```

Comment: Is "Move down" supposed to be the "title" that you want to stay in the middle?

Comment: The code here is clearer http://jsfiddle.net/78x6nwef/

Comment: I used this (margin: 10px 5px 15px 110px;) to move between left and right and make it in the middle
But the result varies with the size of the phone screens, the tags are not left in the middle

Comment: what are those br  can you show how your text is wrapped?

Comment: which content should be in center the a  or the text?

Answer (score -1):

just add `text-align: center` to your `after` element